# como mostrar un valor selected en un select que trae datos de una tabla mysql y se estan mostrando en una tabla alguien podria help me?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

lo que necesito es que cuando se de click en editar me aparezca como selected el registro que pertenece a ese usuario por ejemplo el genero que aparezcan todos los generos y el genero de usuario selected, no se me ocurre como hacerlo alguien sabe como hacerlo le agradeceria que me ayudaran
este es el codigo que muestra los datos

```
 <table class="tablaregistros" border=1; cellspacing=0;>
            <tr align="center" ; style="height:2rem;">
                <td>Tipo de documento</td>
                <td>Documento</td>
                <td>Nombres</td>
                <td>Apellidos</td>
                <td>Celular</td>
                <td>Correo</td>
                <td>Genero</td>
                <td>Fecha de nacimiento</td>
                <td>Departamento</td>
                <td>Municipio</td>
                <td>Barrio</td>
                <td>Direccion</td>
                <td>Eps</td>
                <td>Regimen</td>
                <td>Ips primaria</td>
                <td>Estado usuario</td>
                <td>Acciones</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $con = "SELECT * from usuario inner join barrio using(idbarrio) inner join instituciones using(nitinstitucion) 
            inner join genero using(idgenero)  inner join eps using(ideps) inner join regimen using(idregimen) inner join 
            tipodocumento using(idtipodocumento) inner join estados using(idestado) inner join municipios using(id_municipio)
            inner join departamentos using(id_departamento) where itipousuario = 12";
            $m = mysqli_query($mysqli, $con);
            while($eh = mysqli_fetch_array($m)){           
            ?>

            <tr align="center" ; style="height:2rem;">
                <td><?php echo $eh['tipodocumento']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['documento']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['nombres']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['apellidos']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['celular']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['correousuario']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['genero']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['fechanacimiento']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['departamento']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['municipio']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['barrio']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['direccionusuario']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['nombreeps']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['regimen']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['nombreips']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $eh['estadousuario']?></td>

este es el codigo de la ventana modal la cual debe de mostrar los datos del usuario para que el los pueda editar el caso es que no me aparecen los selects los de los inputs los he podido hacer mediante jquery pero los selects nos se como para que aparezcan selected el que le corresponde al usuario

                <td><a href="#modaleditar" class="editbtn"></p><img style="width:1.5rem;"
                            src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" /></a>
                    <a href="../../includes/eliminaradmin.php?id=<?php echo $eh['documento'];?>"
                        class="table__item__link"><img style="width:1.5rem;"
                            src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9IjUxMnB0IiB2aWV3Qm94PSItNTcgMCA1MTIgNTEyIiB3aWR0aD0iNTEycHQiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0ibTE1Ni4zNzEwOTQgMzAuOTA2MjVoODUuNTcwMzEydjE0LjM5ODQzOGgzMC45MDIzNDR2LTE2LjQxNDA2M2MuMDAzOTA2LTE1LjkyOTY4Ny0xMi45NDkyMTktMjguODkwNjI1LTI4Ljg3MTA5NC0yOC44OTA2MjVoLTg5LjYzMjgxMmMtMTUuOTIxODc1IDAtMjguODc1IDEyLjk2MDkzOC0yOC44NzUgMjguODkwNjI1djE2LjQxNDA2M2gzMC45MDYyNXptMCAwIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTM0NC4yMTA5MzggMTY3Ljc1aC0yOTAuMTA5Mzc2Yy03Ljk0OTIxOCAwLTE0LjIwNzAzMSA2Ljc4MTI1LTEzLjU2NjQwNiAxNC43MDcwMzFsMjQuMjUzOTA2IDI5OS45MDYyNWMxLjM1MTU2MyAxNi43NDIxODggMTUuMzE2NDA3IDI5LjYzNjcxOSAzMi4wOTM3NSAyOS42MzY3MTloMjA0LjU0Mjk2OWMxNi43NzczNDQgMCAzMC43NDIxODgtMTIuODk0NTMxIDMyLjA5Mzc1LTI5LjY0MDYyNWwyNC4yNTM5MDctMjk5LjkwMjM0NGMuNjQ0NTMxLTcuOTI1NzgxLTUuNjEzMjgyLTE0LjcwNzAzMS0xMy41NjI1LTE0LjcwNzAzMXptLTIxOS44NjMyODIgMzEyLjI2MTcxOWMtLjMyNDIxOC4wMTk1MzEtLjY0ODQzNy4wMzEyNS0uOTY4NzUuMDMxMjUtOC4xMDE1NjIgMC0xNC45MDIzNDQtNi4zMDg1OTQtMTUuNDA2MjUtMTQuNTAzOTA3bC0xNS4xOTkyMTgtMjQ2LjIwNzAzMWMtLjUyMzQzOC04LjUxOTUzMSA1Ljk1NzAzMS0xNS44NTE1NjIgMTQuNDcyNjU2LTE2LjM3NSA4LjQ4ODI4MS0uNTE1NjI1IDE1Ljg1MTU2MiA1Ljk0OTIxOSAxNi4zNzUgMTQuNDcyNjU3bDE1LjE5NTMxMiAyNDYuMjA3MDMxYy41MjczNDQgOC41MTk1MzEtNS45NTMxMjUgMTUuODQ3NjU2LTE0LjQ2ODc1IDE2LjM3NXptOTAuNDMzNTk0LTE1LjQyMTg3NWMwIDguNTMxMjUtNi45MTc5NjkgMTUuNDQ5MjE4LTE1LjQ1MzEyNSAxNS40NDkyMThzLTE1LjQ1MzEyNS02LjkxNzk2OC0xNS40NTMxMjUtMTUuNDQ5MjE4di0yNDYuMjEwOTM4YzAtOC41MzUxNTYgNi45MTc5NjktMTUuNDUzMTI1IDE1LjQ1MzEyNS0xNS40NTMxMjUgOC41MzEyNSAwIDE1LjQ1MzEyNSA2LjkxNzk2OSAxNS40NTMxMjUgMTUuNDUzMTI1em05MC43NTc4MTItMjQ1LjMwMDc4Mi0xNC41MTE3MTggMjQ2LjIwNzAzMmMtLjQ4MDQ2OSA4LjIxMDkzNy03LjI5Mjk2OSAxNC41NDI5NjgtMTUuNDEwMTU2IDE0LjU0Mjk2OC0uMzA0Njg4IDAtLjYxMzI4Mi0uMDA3ODEyLS45MjE4NzYtLjAyMzQzNy04LjUxOTUzMS0uNTAzOTA2LTE1LjAxOTUzMS03LjgxNjQwNi0xNC41MTU2MjQtMTYuMzM1OTM3bDE0LjUwNzgxMi0yNDYuMjEwOTM4Yy41LTguNTE5NTMxIDcuNzg5MDYyLTE1LjAxOTUzMSAxNi4zMzIwMzEtMTQuNTE1NjI1IDguNTE5NTMxLjUgMTUuMDE5NTMxIDcuODE2NDA2IDE0LjUxOTUzMSAxNi4zMzU5Mzd6bTAgMCIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0zOTcuNjQ4NDM4IDEyMC4wNjI1LTEwLjE0ODQzOC0zMC40MjE4NzVjLTIuNjc1NzgxLTguMDE5NTMxLTEwLjE4MzU5NC0xMy40Mjk2ODctMTguNjQwNjI1LTEzLjQyOTY4N2gtMzM5LjQxMDE1NmMtOC40NTMxMjUgMC0xNS45NjQ4NDQgNS40MTAxNTYtMTguNjM2NzE5IDEzLjQyOTY4N2wtMTAuMTQ4NDM4IDMwLjQyMTg3NWMtMS45NTcwMzEgNS44NjcxODguNTg5ODQ0IDExLjg1MTU2MiA1LjM0Mzc1IDE0LjgzNTkzOCAxLjkzNzUgMS4yMTQ4NDMgNC4yMzA0NjkgMS45NDUzMTIgNi43NSAxLjk0NTMxMmgzNzIuNzk2ODc2YzIuNTE5NTMxIDAgNC44MTY0MDYtLjczMDQ2OSA2Ljc1LTEuOTQ5MjE5IDQuNzUzOTA2LTIuOTg0Mzc1IDcuMzAwNzgxLTguOTY4NzUgNS4zNDM3NS0xNC44MzIwMzF6bTAgMCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==" /></a>
                </td>
                


            </tr>
            <?php
            } 
            ?>
        </table>
```

este es el codigo de la ventana modal la cual muestra los datos del usuario para que el pueda editar su informacion, pero no he logrado que los selects aparezcan selected los del usuario ya que los selects los muestro mediante consultas a la base de datos mysql

```
<div id="modaleditar" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            
            <div class="crear">

                <form action="" method="post" id="formulariopaciente">

                    <br>
                    <h3>Editar</h3>
                    <br>

                    <!--select para el tipo de documento-->
                    <label for="tipdoc" class="labels" style="margin-left:-28rem;">Tipo de documento</label>
                    <select name="tipdoc" id="tipdoc" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <?php 
                        $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from tipodocumento");
                        while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
                     
                        
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>


                    <!--inputs de datos basicos del paciente-->

                    <input type="number" placeholder="documento" name="documento" class="objeto documento"
                        id="documento" style="color:gray;">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="nombres" name="nombres" class="objeto nombres" id="nombres"
                        style="color:gray;">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="objeto apellidos" id="apellidos"
                        style="color:gray;">

                    <input type="number" placeholder="celular" name="celular" class="objeto celular" id="celular"
                        style="color:gray;">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="correo" name="correo" class=" correo"
                        style="width:186px;color:gray;" id="email">
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <label for="genero" style="margin-left:-33rem;">Genero</label>
                    <select name="genero" id="genero" class="select-css" style="width:190px;" style="color:gray;">
                        <?php 
                        $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from genero");
                        while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
                     
                        
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>
                    <label for="" style="position:absolute; left:14rem; top:12.3rem;">Fecha nacimiento</label>

                    <input type="date" name="fechanaci" class="objeto date" id="fechanac" placeholder="fechanacimiento"
                        style="color:gray;">


                    <!--select para traer el departamento-->
                    <label for="id_departamento"
                        style="position:absolute;right:7.2rem;top:12.3rem;">Departamento</label>

                    <select id="departamentoeditar" class="select-css" style="width:190px;" style="color:gray;">
                        <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>
                        <?php  
             
                             $conf = new Configuracion();
                                 $conf->conectarBD();                                                                             
                                 $consulta = "SELECT id_departamento,departamento FROM departamentos";
                                 $rst1 = $conf->consulta($consulta);
                                  for($i = 0; $i < count($rst1); $i++)
                             {                                                   
                                echo '<option value="'.$rst1[$i]["id_departamento"].'">'.$rst1[$i]["departamento"].'</option>';                                                    
                                 }
                                $conf->desconectarDB();
                                 ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <!--municipio-->
                    <br>

                    <label for="" style="margin-left:-32rem;">Municipio</label>

                    <select id="municipioeditar" name="municipio" class="select-css" style="width:190px;" style="color:gray">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                    <!--funcion ajax para traer el municipio acorde al departamento-->
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var municipio = $('#municipioeditar');
                        $('#departamentoeditar').change(function() {
                            var departamento = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    departamento: departamento
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../getmunicipiomodal.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                municipio.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>

                    <!--barrio acorde al municipio seleccionado-->
                    <label for="" style="position:absolute; left:13.8rem;top:16.3rem;">Barrio</label>
                    <select id="id_barrioeditar" name="barrio" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var barrio = $('#id_barrioeditar');
                        $('#municipioeditar').change(function() {
                            var id_municipio = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    id_municipio: id_municipio
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../getbarrio.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                barrio.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="direccion" name="direccion" class="objeto direccion" id="direccion"
                        style="color:gray;">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                      
                    <label for="" style="position:absolute;top:20.3rem; left:2rem;">Regimen</label>
                    <select name="regimen" id="regimeneditar" class="select-css" style="width:190px;position:absolute;left:1.6rem;">
                        <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>
                        <?php  
             
                             $conf = new Configuracion();
                                 $conf->conectarBD();                                                                             
                                 $consulta = "SELECT idregimen,regimen FROM regimen where idregimen > 1";
                                 $rst1 = $conf->consulta($consulta);
                                  for($i = 0; $i < count($rst1); $i++)
                             {                                                   
                                echo '<option value="'.$rst1[$i]["idregimen"].'">'.$rst1[$i]["regimen"].'</option>';                                                    
                                 }
                                $conf->desconectarDB();
                                 ?>
                    </select>



                        
                    <!--inician los datos de afiliacion mas importantes-->
                    <label for="" style="position:absolute;top:20.3rem; left:14rem;">Eps</label>
                    <select id="epseditar" name="eps" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                    <!--funcion ajax para traer el municipio acorde al departamento-->
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var eps = $('#epseditar');
                        $('#regimeneditar').change(function() {
                            var regimen = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    regimen: regimen
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../geteps.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                eps.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>

                    



                    <label for="" style="position:absolute;left:25.6rem; top:20.3rem">Ips primaria</label>
                    <br>
                    <select id="id_ipseditar" name="ips" class="select-css"
                        style="width:190px; position:absolute; left:26rem; top:21.5rem;">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var ips = $('#id_ipseditar');
                        $('#municipioeditar').change(function() {
                            var id_municipio = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    id_municipio: id_municipio
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../getips.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                ips.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>


                    <div id="empresa" style="display:none;">
                        <label for="" style="position:absolute;top:21rem; left:12.8rem;">Empresa donde trabaja</label>
                        <select id="id_empresa" name="empresa" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var id_empresa = $('#id_empresa');

                        $('#id_municipio').change(function() {
                            var id_municipio = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    id_municipio: id_municipio
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../getempresa.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                id_empresa.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                    <!--codigo para bloquear el select de la empresa si el paciente es desempleado-->
                    <script>
                    $('#estadolaboral').change(function() {
                        var estadolaboral = $(this).val();
                        if (estadolaboral == 1) {
                            document.getElementById("empresa").style.display = "block";
                        } else {}
                    });
                    </script>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <label for="tipdoc" class="labels" style="">Estado usuario</label>
                    <select name="tipdoc" id="municipio" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <?php 
                        $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from estados where idestado = 10 or idestado = 11");
                        while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
                     
                        
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" id="afiliarpaciente" name="ok" class="ok">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo como realizo yo los selected.

```
 <option value="<?=$item['id']?>" <?= ($resultado_producto['idcategory'] == $item['id']) ? 'selected' : ''  ?>  > <?= $item['nombre'] ?>  </option>
```

Espero puedas adaptarlo a tu codigo.

Comment: gracias, pero no entiendo la variable resultado_producto que es?